# restore os x from specific time machine backup

Tags: macos, mac, backup, restore, time-machine

I upgraded to yosemite, but it was killing my computer, so I decided to restore my compute from a time machine backup I have on an external hard drive.

My time machine backup directory `Backups.backupdb` on the external drive has two subdirectories:

- `printer`       (the old name of my computer, latest backup 2014-08-21)
- `Giulio MacBook Pro` (In august Apple formatted my HD to solve a hardware issue I reinstalled with this new name, this is the backup I would like to revert to, latest backup on 2014-10-24)

I just restarted my computer holding cmd+r button, and selected "restore a time machine backup option", it took a couple of hours but then the computer correctly booted up.

I didn't notice anything wrong and I started using my computer. At some point I noticed time machine complaining that it was more than 60 days since the last backup, that's when I realised also that the name of the computer isn't `giulio MacBook...` but it's `printer`, the old name, I suspect that I got the older backup restored.

I'm not sure what happened, but I feel that the backup I got restored is actually the older one.  I would like to restore to the newer backup, to get the machine with the `Giulio MacBook Pro` name and other configurations.

If this wasn't enough I tried replugging my time machine backup disk, to understand what was the problem. And the computer started immediately to make a new backup, and I'm not sure what it did there, but the `Giulio MacBook Pro` directory disappeared, and got replaced with another one called `printer 2`

this new directory contains directories with the backup dates, and it seems that there I can find the latest backup of `2014-10-24`, so it seems that Time machine didn't delete its backups but just renamed the directory.

I would like to understand what happened, and how can I restore my time machine from 2014-10-24, I'm worried that if I redo the restore again it will just reinstall the version of 2014-08-21.

thanks